# Eigenvalues of a new matrix obtained by linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

We have a random vector of *X* that has 3 columns. It has a covariance matrix, say *S*. S has three eigenvectors: *e1*, *e2*, and *e3*. *P* is given as horizontal concatenation of these eigenvectors, *[e1 e2 e3]*. A new random vector *Y* is constructed as *Y=P'X*.

How do we prove that *YY'=X'X*?